# Doesn't display all labels of the arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, jlabel

I have a problem that  I can't display all the labels in the window

I created 20 labels in the arraylist, but sometimes I get 10, another I got 14 later it became 19 (from 0 to 19). So it cant't display all the labels from the first time.

```
package Windows;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Protofenetre extends JFrame {

    public JPanel panneau;
    public ArrayList<JLabel> labels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();


    public Protofenetre ()
    {
        this.setTitle ("The Scopy Zoo :D");

        this.setSize(500, 500);

        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        this.setVisible(true); 

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panneau = new JPanel();


        panneau.setLayout(null);

        this.setContentPane(panneau);



    }

}
```

Here is my Main CLass

```
package Concession;

    import javax.swing.JLabel;

    import Windows.Protofenetre;

    public class Main_Class {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Protofenetre fenetre = new Protofenetre ();

        for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
        {   
            JLabel temp = new JLabel();
            temp.setBounds(20, i*20, 200, 100);
            temp.setText("pixels" + String.valueOf(i));
            temp.setVisible(true);
            fenetre.panneau.add(temp);
            fenetre.labels.add(temp);
        }           
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to set a layout to `panneau`? [Here is a link describing the different layouts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: Have you tried to create a list just before your loop, add the Labels to the list, before subsequently adding the list to the frame? I think the labels are being added, but never properly rendered. You can try to reload or redraw or validate the frame after everything has been added.

Comment: It's working just if I delete the set layout
    panneau.setLayout(null);

Comment: The layout is responsible for putting the components in the right order. The default layout of a JPanel is a flow layout. If you set null, there will be no layout and your labels will not be drawn correctly.

Comment: You could also try to call the `fenetre.panneau.validate()` after your for loop.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I used validate () method of the panel, and it's working, just it's still taking little bit of time